# Selecting Encrypted Data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am storing some encrypted information in a MySQL database, but I can't get it back out for some reason.  I am storing the encrypted data as **BINARY(46)**.  Why is my select statement failing?

Here is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT max(created) FROM incentive_sales WHERE incentive_sales.accountID = :aid
```

So shouldn't I encrypt the accountID (:aid) for my select statement?

Here is my encrypt function:

```
private function _encrypt($decrypted, $password, $salt = '|SgQLL*ea!UMwf^s%'){
  // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
  $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);
  // Build $iv and $iv_base64.  We use a block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode.  (Note: ECB mode is inadequate as IV is not used.)
  srand(); $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
  if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22){
    return false;    
  }
  // Encrypt $decrypted using $key.
  $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
  return $iv_base64.$encrypted;
}
```

And my decrypt function:

```
private function _decrypt($encrypted, $password, $salt = '|SgQLL*ea!UMwf^s%'){
  // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
  $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);
  // Retrieve $iv which is the first 22 characters plus ==, base64_decoded.
  $iv = base64_decode(substr($encrypted, 0, 22) . '==');
  // Remove $iv from $encrypted.
  $encrypted = substr($encrypted, 22);
  // Decrypt the data.
  $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
  return $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Which field is BINARY type? accountID or created or some other field.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ accoundID

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is, "As far as I know, you cannot use encrypted data as a selection in the where clause because it will always be different."

To circumvent this (because I do want to be able to select based on the encrypted data), I also store a hashed/salted value of the encrypted data which I then use in my select statement.